# How to get text from TextArea in JavaFX saving line breaks?

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

I have a TextArea and a few lines of text in it. When I extract String by getText() method what I`m getting is a line of text instead of really written few lines. So what can I do to distinguishevery line in TextArea?

Comment: If the user is pressing enter to create new lines, then those new line characters (`"\n"`) will be part of what you receive from `getText()`. If the text area is just wrapping words at the physical edge of the text area, there are no line breaks (which makes sense, as it just depends on the size of the text area, not on the what the user has actually typed). Can you explain more thoroughly what is happening and why you think there are new line characters missing?

Comment: Where you put this extracted text ?

Comment: The new line characters are missing exactly when text is moved to another line because of set wrap, but not because of user pressed enter.

Comment: I put extracted text into String variable.

Comment: So how can i get the number of characters in every line of the TextArea?

Comment: If the lines are simply due to wrapping, you can't. The text is just the text that the user entered (or that was set programmatically). The line breaks created by word wrapping are simply aspects of the display. If you want the displayed lines to exactly match the text data, then you should turn wrapping off, so the user is forced to break lines where they intend. It's not really clear what you are trying to do, or why.

Comment: But to answer the question in the previous comment, the lengths of the actual lines of text entered by the user (i.e. not due to wrapping) is given by `List<Integer> lineLengths = Stream.of(textArea.getText().split("\n")).map(String::length).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: I`m trying to do so that user don`t have to explicitly enter line break every time he or she is typing into textarea. But I want line breaks to appear in the String extracted from textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **.replaceAll** like this,

```
//replace the line breaks "\n" with System line separator...
//replace "yourTextAreaVariabe" with your own...
yourTextAreaVariable.getText().replaceAll("\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```